# how to add custom filter in UI component with minimum effort?

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I have grid in which i try to filter a field name "seller_id" and this grid is a coming from a custom dataprovider with join of two tables.

Now the issue is these both table have same column name "seller_id" due to which it throws **ambiguous column error** upon filtering the column "seller_id".

Answer (score 0):

Make use of select and alias in join might resolve your issue

Comment: already have alias but when i filter them it shows error

Comment: Share your code

Comment: shared my answer, thanks for the help its resolved

Answer (score 0):

write this function in dataprovider file

```
    /**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter
 */
public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
{
    if($filter->getField() === 'seller_id') {
        $filter->setField("main_table.".$filter->getField());
    }
    $joinRefField = "main_table.".$filter->getField();
    if (isset($this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()])) {
        $this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()]
            ->addFilter(
                $this->getCollection(),
                $joinRefField,
                [$filter->getConditionType() => $filter->getValue()]
            );

    } else {
        parent::addFilter($filter);
    }
}
```

as you were getting column name in " $filter->getField() " so you need to modify where query using the first **if condition**